# Count until reaching specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have following data set representing my problem:

```
1
2
3
1
2
1
2
3
4
```

What i want to achieve is to count until reaching value "1" so it would look something like this:

```
1 3 
2
3
1 2
2
1 4
2
3
4
```

I've tried to use countif but failing hard. I don't know how to set the proper arguments for this. Thanks for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 4):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1=1,COUNT(A1:$A$9999)-SUM(B2:$B$9999),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

So column **B** represents the number of items in each block in column **A** that begins with a *1*.

Comment: It's tricky one ,,,☺ +10 .

Comment: @RajeshS  **You are correct !** The tricky part is the subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

[Gary's Student’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1448708/150988#1448733) produces correct results. 
But,

- It doesn’t work until Column B is filled in all the way.
- At every row, it needs to look at every row from itself to Row 9999. 
  It seems that this could be computationally expensive
  if there are, in fact, thousands of rows of data.

A more efficient, self-contained answer is

```
=IF(A1=1, MATCH(1,A2:A$9999,0), "")
```

As in the other answer, this does nothing (and displays blank) on rows
where the value in Column A is not a 1. 
If it is a 1, the formula simply searches down Column A to find the next 1.

Unfortunately, this will fail for the last block,
because there is no *next* 1. 
To solve that, we do

```
=IF(A1=1, IFERROR(MATCH(1,A2:A$9999,0), COUNT(A1:A$9999)), "")
```

i.e., if there is no next 1, we must be in the last block,
so just count the remaining non-blank cells. 
No need to do any arithmetic.

Here, Column B is Gary's Student’s formula,
Column C is my first formula, and Column D is my second formula:

[image: spreadsheet, comparing competing formulas]